# Why is Nuget randomly crashing when restoring packages via command line?

Tags: .net, powershell, clr, nuget

We don't commit the `packages` folder to our repositories. Additionally, rather than restoring packages at build time (since it can increase build time), we restore packages with the following PowerShell Module when we clone/checkout a fresh repository:

```
$rootDir = resolve-path "$PSScriptRoot\.."
$nugetRoot = "$rootDir\.nuget"

$env:path += ";$nugetRoot"

function Restore-Packages() {

    $packageSources = @(
        "$nugetRoot",
        "$rootDir/db",
        "$rootDir/src",
        "$rootDir/test"
    )

    $packageSources | dir -r -include "packages.config" | % {
        $configPath = $_.FullName

        $configName = $configPath.Replace($rootDir.ToString() + "\", "")

        write-host "Installing packages for " -n
        write-host "$configName" -f "white"

        nuget install "$configPath" -solutionDir "$rootDir"
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember Restore-Packages
```

This works great ... but can randomly *not* work! Sometimes, all of the packages are loaded correctly and other times **random** `package.config` files crash Nuget!

There is no error message printed to the console (even with the `-verbosity detailed` switch on nuget.exe). However, I did find that the EventLog was getting an error message:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          11/21/2012 9:21:42 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Description:
Faulting application name: NuGet.exe, version: 2.1.31022.9038, time stamp: 0x50856393
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.239, time stamp: 0x4e181a6d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0035612d
Faulting process id: 0x408
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdc7eb24bed690
Faulting application path: D:\path\to\app\.nuget\NuGet.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 63343f50-33de-11e2-b0e1-005056c00008
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-11-21T13:21:42.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>77009</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>NuGet.exe</Data>
    <Data>2.1.31022.9038</Data>
    <Data>50856393</Data>
    <Data>clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>4.0.30319.239</Data>
    <Data>4e181a6d</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>0035612d</Data>
    <Data>408</Data>
    <Data>01cdc7eb24bed690</Data>
    <Data>D:\path\to\app\.nuget\NuGet.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>63343f50-33de-11e2-b0e1-005056c00008</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Because this silently fails, other `package.config`s may or may not be run after one has crashed (it could crash too!).

I've rebooted my computer several times and cleared the Nuget cache, but to no avail. Is this a problem with my machine? Is it Nuget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your script and it worked fine for me. One thing I might try is replacing nuget.exe with a fresh download from http://nuget.org/nuget.exe

Another thing I would try is if nuget.exe crashes if run directly from the command line?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying it. So the odd thing is that it works for me too... but then sometimes fails! The error from the event log is the only error of it failing that I can find. However, sometimes it runs completely OK.